# buildship eclipse plugin for gradle not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, buildship

I have just installed the `buildship` eclipse plugin for gradle. I am using the following eclipse:

```
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500
```

When I try to Import or Create a New project I don't get the expected Gradle project wizard. Without this I am not sure how else I would make use of this plugin. I can't find any view etc as well. Do I need to install something else with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had my eclipse installed in Program Files folder. I moved the installation to a another folder eg: `c:\eclipse` and then reinstalled the plugin. I now get the wizard. I also installed the older gradle plugin - not sure if this has an impact on the installation. Anyway the buildship doesn't work when eclipse is located under Program File.

To rule out issues with permission, I ran my eclipse as Admin and then installed the plugin - even after this it doesn't work.